# Creating an OFX file which an be opened by Quicken (v6.12.3) for macOS

Tags: python, ofx, quicken

I have some investment accounts which I am tracking with Quicken for *macOS*. However, I am using the Quicken feature to auto-download the status of the account. However, the company does not support downloading the individual transactions, which I would like to also track inside of Quicken. But, I do not want enter these transitions manually. The do allow me to download the transactions as a CSV file. I had the idea of taking that CSV file and converting it to OFX which Quicken should be able to import. However, the OFX file I am creating is not valid and I am not sure how to fix it so Quicken will import it.

The data below is mocked, but is same format.

When I try to import the OFX file, the error I get from Quicken is:

```
This FI is inactive, we cannot connect.
```

If I remove the FI block, I get the error:

```
Unable to read the selected Web Connect file.
```

How can I change the OFX file?

The CSV file is:

```
Brokerage

Run Date,Action,Symbol,Security Description,Security Type,Quantity,Price ($),Commission ($),Fees ($),Accrued Interest ($),Amount ($),Settlement Date
01/02/2023,YOU BOUGHT,A,AGILENT TECHNOLOGIES INC,Cash,42,84,,,,-3528.00,01/03/2023
01/03/2023, YOU BOUGHT,AA,ALCOA CORPORATION,Cash,43,86,,,,-3698.00,01/04/2023
01/04/2023, YOU BOUGHT,AAC,ARES ACQUISITION CORP,Cash,44,88,,,,-3872.00,01/05/2023
```

The OFX file I am creating is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?OFX OFXHEADER="200" VERSION="220" SECURITY="NONE" OLDFILEUID="NONE" NEWFILEUID="NONE"?>
<OFX>
  <SIGNONMSGSRSV1>
    <SONRS>
      <STATUS>
        <CODE>0</CODE>
        <SEVERITY>INFO</SEVERITY>
      </STATUS>
      <DTSERVER>20230304170917.174[+0:UTC]</DTSERVER>
      <LANGUAGE>ENG</LANGUAGE>
      <FI>
        <ORG>Investments</ORG>
        <FID>1234</FID>
      </FI>
    </SONRS>
  </SIGNONMSGSRSV1>
  <INVSTMTMSGSRSV1>
    <INVSTMTTRNRS>
      <TRNUID>0</TRNUID>
      <STATUS>
        <CODE>0</CODE>
        <SEVERITY>INFO</SEVERITY>
      </STATUS>
      <INVSTMTRS>
        <DTASOF>20230304170917.178[+0:UTC]</DTASOF>
        <CURDEF>USD</CURDEF>
        <INVACCTFROM>
          <BROKERID>investments.com</BROKERID>
          <ACCTID>Y12345678</ACCTID>
        </INVACCTFROM>
        <INVTRANLIST>
          <DTSTART>20230102000000.000[+0:UTC]</DTSTART>
          <DTEND>20230104000000.000[+0:UTC]</DTEND>
          <BUYOTHER>
            <INVBUY>
              <INVTRAN>
                <FITID>725bb8d9-ef22-4b9b-9214-8080a4a59ddb</FITID>
                <DTTRADE>20230102000000.000[+0:UTC]</DTTRADE>
                <DTSETTLE>20230103000000.000[+0:UTC]</DTSETTLE>
              </INVTRAN>
              <SECID>
                <UNIQUEID>100000000</UNIQUEID>
                <UNIQUEIDTYPE>OTHER</UNIQUEIDTYPE>
              </SECID>
              <UNITS>42</UNITS>
              <UNITPRICE>84</UNITPRICE>
              <TOTAL>3528</TOTAL>
              <SUBACCTSEC>CASH</SUBACCTSEC>
              <SUBACCTFUND>CASH</SUBACCTFUND>
            </INVBUY>
          </BUYOTHER>
          <BUYOTHER>
            <INVBUY>
              <INVTRAN>
                <FITID>a04dad7f-7374-4920-bf1c-ed90bdef5991</FITID>
                <DTTRADE>20230103000000.000[+0:UTC]</DTTRADE>
                <DTSETTLE>20230104000000.000[+0:UTC]</DTSETTLE>
              </INVTRAN>
              <SECID>
                <UNIQUEID>100000001</UNIQUEID>
                <UNIQUEIDTYPE>OTHER</UNIQUEIDTYPE>
              </SECID>
              <UNITS>43</UNITS>
              <UNITPRICE>86</UNITPRICE>
              <TOTAL>3698</TOTAL>
              <SUBACCTSEC>CASH</SUBACCTSEC>
              <SUBACCTFUND>CASH</SUBACCTFUND>
            </INVBUY>
          </BUYOTHER>
          <BUYOTHER>
            <INVBUY>
              <INVTRAN>
                <FITID>f2a9db1d-22e8-43ea-aab9-ad9c27e40cee</FITID>
                <DTTRADE>20230104000000.000[+0:UTC]</DTTRADE>
                <DTSETTLE>20230105000000.000[+0:UTC]</DTSETTLE>
              </INVTRAN>
              <SECID>
                <UNIQUEID>100000002</UNIQUEID>
                <UNIQUEIDTYPE>OTHER</UNIQUEIDTYPE>
              </SECID>
              <UNITS>44</UNITS>
              <UNITPRICE>88</UNITPRICE>
              <TOTAL>3872</TOTAL>
              <SUBACCTSEC>CASH</SUBACCTSEC>
              <SUBACCTFUND>CASH</SUBACCTFUND>
            </INVBUY>
          </BUYOTHER>
        </INVTRANLIST>
      </INVSTMTRS>
    </INVSTMTTRNRS>
  </INVSTMTMSGSRSV1>
  <SECLISTMSGSRSV1>
    <SECLIST>
      <MFINFO>
        <SECINFO>
          <SECID>
            <UNIQUEID>100000000</UNIQUEID>
            <UNIQUEIDTYPE>OTHER</UNIQUEIDTYPE>
          </SECID>
          <SECNAME>AGILENT TECHNOLOGIES INC</SECNAME>
          <TICKER>A</TICKER>
        </SECINFO>
      </MFINFO>
      <MFINFO>
        <SECINFO>
          <SECID>
            <UNIQUEID>100000001</UNIQUEID>
            <UNIQUEIDTYPE>OTHER</UNIQUEIDTYPE>
          </SECID>
          <SECNAME>ALCOA CORPORATION</SECNAME>
          <TICKER>AA</TICKER>
        </SECINFO>
      </MFINFO>
      <MFINFO>
        <SECINFO>
          <SECID>
            <UNIQUEID>100000002</UNIQUEID>
            <UNIQUEIDTYPE>OTHER</UNIQUEIDTYPE>
          </SECID>
          <SECNAME>ARES ACQUISITION CORP</SECNAME>
          <TICKER>AAC</TICKER>
        </SECINFO>
      </MFINFO>
    </SECLIST>
  </SECLISTMSGSRSV1>
</OFX>
```

The python code I wrote to do the conversion is:

```
from ofxtools.models import *
from ofxtools.Types import *
from ofxtools.utils import UTC
from decimal import Decimal
from datetime import datetime
from pprint import pprint
from ofxtools.header import make_header

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

import csv
import uuid
import os
import re

PATH   = "History_for_Account_Y12345678.csv"
OUT_PATH = "History_for_Account_Y12345678.ofx"
HEADER = ['Run Date', 'Action', 'Symbol', 'Security Description', 'Security Type', 'Quantity', 'Price ($)', 'Commission ($)', 'Fees ($)', 'Accrued Interest ($)', 'Amount ($)', 'Settlement Date' ]

filename = os.path.basename( PATH )
filename = re.search( ".*_(.*)\.csv", filename )
acctid   = filename.group(1)

def validate_file( lines ):
    if lines[3] != ['Brokerage']:
        print( "[!] Forth line does not contain Brokerage" )
        print( lines[3] )
        return False
    
    fileHeader = lines[5]
    
    if len( HEADER ) != len( fileHeader ):
        print( "[!] Header Length Mismatch" )
        return False
    
    for column in HEADER:
        if column not in fileHeader:
            print( f"[!] Header Column Not Found: {column}" )
            return False

    return True


def extract_unique_securities( lines ):
    lines = lines[1:]
    uniqueSecurities = set()
    identifier = 100000000
    
    for line in lines:
        if line[3].strip() != 'No Description':
            uniqueSecurities.add( ( line[2].strip(), line[3].strip(), identifier ) )
            identifier = identifier + 1
    
    uniqueSecurities = list( uniqueSecurities )
    
    securityMap = {}
    
    for security in uniqueSecurities:
        securityMap[ security[0] ] = security
    
    # pprint( securityMap )
    
    return securityMap


def make_security_list_message_set_response_messages( securityMap ): # SECLISTMSGSRSV1
    
    messages = []
    securityList = []
    
    for security in securityMap.values():
        
        secid   = SECID( uniqueid = str( security[2] ), uniqueidtype = 'OTHER' )
        secname = security[1]
        ticker  = security[0]
        secinfo = SECINFO( secid = secid, secname = secname, ticker = ticker )
        mfinfo  = MFINFO( secinfo = secinfo )
        
        securityList.append( mfinfo )
        
    seclist = SECLIST( *securityList )
    messages = SECLISTMSGSRSV1( seclist )
    
    return messages



def make_investment_statement_message_set_response_messages( securityMap, transactions ):
    
    transactionList = []
    response        = None
    
    trnuid = "0"
    status = STATUS( code = 0, severity = 'INFO' )
    
    startDate = datetime( 3000, 1, 1, tzinfo = UTC )
    endDate = datetime( 1970, 1, 1, tzinfo = UTC )
    
    for transaction in transactions[1:]:
        transactionDate = datetime.strptime( transaction[0].strip(), "%m/%d/%Y" ).replace( tzinfo = UTC )
        
        if startDate > transactionDate:
            startDate = transactionDate
            
        if endDate < transactionDate:
            endDate = transactionDate

        description    = transaction[1].strip()
        symbol         = transaction[2].strip() if len( transaction[2].strip() ) > 0 else None
        securityType   = transaction[4].strip() if len( transaction[4].strip() ) > 0 else None
        quantity       = float( transaction[5].strip() ) if len( transaction[5].strip() ) > 0 else None
        price          = float( transaction[6].strip() ) if len( transaction[6].strip() ) > 0 else None
        fee            = float( transaction[8].strip() ) if len( transaction[8].strip() ) > 0 else None
        amount         = float( transaction[10].strip() ) if len( transaction[10].strip() ) > 0 else None
        settlementDate = datetime.strptime( transaction[11].strip(), "%m/%d/%Y" ).replace( tzinfo = UTC ) if len( transaction[11].strip() ) > 0 else None
        
        # print( f"{transactionDate} {symbol} {quantity} {price} {fee} {amount} {settlementDate}" )
        
        if symbol and amount and quantity and price and securityType == 'Cash':
            
            if amount < 0:
                
                invtran     = INVTRAN( fitid = str( uuid.uuid4() ), dttrade = transactionDate, dtsettle = settlementDate )
                secid       = SECID( uniqueid = str( securityMap[ symbol ][2] ), uniqueidtype = 'OTHER' )
                units       = quantity
                unitprice   = price
                fees        = fee
                total       = amount * -1
                subacctsec  = 'CASH'
                subacctfund = 'CASH'
                
                invbuy      = INVBUY( invtran = invtran, secid = secid, units = units, unitprice = unitprice, fees = fees, total = total, subacctsec = subacctsec, subacctfund = subacctfund )
                buyother    = BUYOTHER( invbuy = invbuy )
                
                transactionList.append( buyother )
                
        else:
            
            print( f"[?] Not Handled {transaction}" )
                
            
        
    invtranlist = INVTRANLIST( dtstart = startDate, dtend = endDate, *transactionList )
    
    currentDate         = datetime.now().replace( tzinfo = UTC )
    invacctfrom         = INVACCTFROM( brokerid = "investments.com", acctid = acctid )
    invstmtrs           = INVSTMTRS( dtasof = currentDate, curdef = 'USD', invacctfrom = invacctfrom, invtranlist = invtranlist  )
    transactionResponse = INVSTMTTRNRS( trnuid = trnuid, status = status, invstmtrs = invstmtrs )
    messages            = INVSTMTMSGSRSV1( transactionResponse )
    
    return messages



def process_file( lines ):
    fileHeader   = r[0]
    transactions = list( filter( lambda line: len( line ) > 1, lines ) )
    
    currentDate = datetime.now().replace( tzinfo = UTC )
    
    securityMap         = extract_unique_securities( transactions )
    securityMessages    = make_security_list_message_set_response_messages( securityMap )
    transactionMessages = make_investment_statement_message_set_response_messages( securityMap, transactions )
    
    status     = STATUS( code = 0, severity = 'INFO' )
    fi         = FI( org = 'Investments', fid = '1234' )
    sonrs      = SONRS( status = status, dtserver = currentDate, language='ENG', fi = fi )
    signonmsgs = SIGNONMSGSRSV1( sonrs = sonrs )

    ofx  = OFX( signonmsgsrsv1 = signonmsgs, seclistmsgsrsv1 = securityMessages, invstmtmsgsrsv1 = transactionMessages )
    root = ofx.to_etree()
    
    ET.indent( root )

    fileData = ET.tostring( root ).decode()
    
    header = str( make_header( version = 220 ) )
    
    # print( header ) 
    # print( fileData )
    
    with open( OUT_PATH, "w" ) as fp:
        fp.write( header )
        fp.write( fileData )

    
    
with open(PATH, newline='') as f:
    fileLines = list( csv.reader( f ) )
  
if validate_file( fileLines ):
    process_file( fileLines[5:] )
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I believe the answer is relatively simple. The only difference between QFX and OFX is those FI blocks. Their purpose is to enforce financial institutions signing up and paying Intuit for data exchange compatibility. In order to work, the org and fid need to be on the list of subscribers.

Oh, and also you need an <INTU.BID> right after the FI block. Best bet is to download a QFX file from an institution that supports Quicken and model after that.

Comment: That has been my understanding and I would likely move forward with that solution if I didn't need to reverse engineer the format to discover all the points where it differs. Hopefully, the Quicken team will offer a supported solution at some point.